# R double for loop over a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix

I have trouble when I make the double for loop for a huge list, the code is like:

```
bootk=0
bias=0
Nk=0
#datalist = list()
for (i in 1:ksign){
for (j in 1:boottime){
    if (i<=ksign1[j]){
        bias[i]=bias[i]+(bigmatrix[,j]$V1.x[i]-bigmatrix[,j]$V1.y[i])
        Nk[i]=Nk[i]+1
        
      }
    }
  }
```

ksign and boottime are just 2 numbers here.
bigmatrix is like a huge list:

```
          [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]         
Row.names Character,269 Character,266 Character,283 Character,273 Character,270
V1.x      Numeric,269   Numeric,266   Numeric,283   Numeric,273   Numeric,270  
V2.x      Numeric,269   Numeric,266   Numeric,283   Numeric,273   Numeric,270  
V1.y      Numeric,269   Numeric,266   Numeric,283   Numeric,273   Numeric,270  
V2.y      Numeric,269   Numeric,266   Numeric,283   Numeric,273   Numeric,270
```

which is a combination of several list depends on the value of boottime. Here I defined it as 5.
But after I ran the code, the output is like:

```
bias
  [1] 2.521886       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
  [9]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [17]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [25]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [33]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

I should have a list of bias, which the number is the value of ksign.
What happened here? Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the data, but you probably have `NA`s in your big matrix or you are indexing out of range. E.g.if  `y <- 1:9` then `y[10]` returns `NA`.

Comment: Make a small, reproducible example of dimension 2x4 to demonstrate what is going wrong. This will help you understand the problem better and help us help you. You could also manually set `i` and `j` to 1 and 2, respectively and see what the calculating expressions returns. This way, you can "manually" debug what is going on.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *bias* is not initialized as a vector, but as a scalar:

```
bias <- 0
bias[1] <- bias[1] + 2  # ok: bias[1] == bias
bias[2] <- bias[2] + 3  # not ok: bias[2] is uninitialized and thus NA
```

results in `(2  NA)` for *bias*.